# How to handle the dynamic URL path and process the request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, dynamic-testing

I am trying to handle the dynamic path of an HTTP request using JMeter. But I am not able to do so. I have tried post processor in a previous HTTP request to get the next HTTP request dynamic path but it is not working. Please guide me.

**Dynamic path:**

[image: Path]

The complete path looks like as below mentioned an example.

```
abc.c_o_m/en/book/confirm/VZM5O/ARL715?tfk=tfk59771a9df0fbd4.08848159
```

**Post Regular expression:**

[image: Post Regular Expression Extractor]

After execution, I have checked in debug sampler but ${Path} contains only default value `i.e. 0.`

Answer (score 2):

Your Regular Expression Extractor configuration is a little bit incorrect:

1. You should change "Field to check" of your Regular Expression Extractor to `URL`
2. You should amend your Regular Expression to something like: `/en/book/confirm/(.*)`

In your current setup your Regular Expression looks into the Response Message (which is `OK` for [HTTP Status Code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200)) and extracts the first letter only from it, which is `0`

Example Regular Expression Configuration:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Configuration]

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Demo]

References:

- [Apache JMeter - User's Manual: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Currently i am facing one more issue that Dynamic URL path is changed on same HTTP request and site navigate to the next step by using this Dynamic URL path using same URL. This path is not known to previous HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some code at browser which would be decrypting the password before sending it.You need to get that code. Capture the value and pass it in that code before sending it.

It might be written in javascript, else check what it is doing and replicate same in BeanShell.

Read more: https://softwaretestingboard.com/q2a/3381/